# Displaying two graphs adjacent to each other with their x-axes aligned (Version 2)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have two graphs drawn using `pgfplots`.  The graphs are drawn as I would like them to be drawn, and the `x`-axes are aligned, as I would like them to be aligned.  There are three modifications that I need.  First, the two graphs should be horizontally centered. Second, more (horizontal) space is needed between the two graphs. Third, a title needs to be centered over the `y`-axis of each graph.  Something like the following code would be suitable.

```
\node[align=center, font=\bfseries, inner sep=0pt, above=3mm] at (current bounding box.north) {The graph of an \\ increasing function};

\node[align=center, font=\bfseries, inner sep=0pt, above=3mm] at (current bounding box.north) {The graph of a strictly \\ increasing function};
```

By the way, in the first graph, I have a horizontal line drawn along the `x`-axis between the origin and `(1,0)`.  Are the axes drawn with a width of `0.8pt`?  I used the option `line width=1.2pt` to draw this horizontal line.  Is that typical when "drawing over" the axes?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image, clip=false,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,ymax=4,
    restrict y to domain=-4:4,
    %enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot [domain=-3:-2] {-3};
\addplot [domain=-2:-1] {-2};
\addplot [domain=-1:0] {-1};
\addplot [line width=1.2pt, domain=0:1] {0};
\addplot [domain=1:2] {1};
\addplot [domain=2:3] {2} node [pos=1, anchor=south west, font=\footnotesize] {$y=f(x)$};

\draw[fill] (-3,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (-2,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (-1,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (1,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (2,2) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\draw [fill=white] (-2,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (-1,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (0,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (2,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (3,2) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in, clip=false,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-8:8,
   % enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot [domain=-2:2] {x^3} node [pos=1, anchor=west, font=\footnotesize] {$y=g(x)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of these things are easily achievable by combining the plots into a single `tikzpicture`.

"First, the two graphs should be horizontally centered."

This is done by surrounding the `tikzpicture` environment with the `center` environment.

"Second, more (horizontal) space is needed between the two graphs."

By placing the two plots in the same `tikzpicture`, we can control their relative positioning by naming the first plot via the `name = <name>` option, and then setting the location of the second plot with `at = (<name>.east)`. Adding `anchor = west` keeps the x-axis alignment. After doing this, the separation distance between the plots can be adjusted via `xshift = <value>`.

"Third, a title needs to be centered over the y-axis of each graph. "

We can just use the `title = {<title>}` option. Note that I added `align = center` in order to achieve the manual line break you wanted.

### Update: Title positioning adjustments

We can add some options in the `title style` to place the title below the axis.

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image, clip=false,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,ymax=4,
    restrict y to domain=-4:4,
    %enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
    title style = {align = center, at = (current axis.south), anchor = north, yshift = -2em},
    title = {The graph of an \\ increasing function}, name = left
]

\addplot [domain=-3:-2] {-3};
\addplot [domain=-2:-1] {-2};
\addplot [domain=-1:0] {-1};
\addplot [line width=1.2pt, domain=0:1] {0};
\addplot [domain=1:2] {1};
\addplot [domain=2:3] {2} node [pos=1, anchor=south west, font=\footnotesize] {$y=f(x)$};

\draw[fill] (-3,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (-2,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (-1,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (1,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (2,2) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\draw [fill=white] (-2,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (-1,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (0,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (2,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (3,2) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[width=3in, clip=false,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-8:8,
   % enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
    title style = {align = center, inner sep = 0pt, above = 3mm},
    title = {The graph of a strictly \\ increasing function},
    at = (left.east), anchor = west, xshift = 2cm
]
\addplot [domain=-2:2] {x^3} node [pos=1, anchor=west, font=\footnotesize] {$y=g(x)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I need more vertical space between the titles and the labels for the `y`-axes.  I had suggested options ` inner sep=0pt` and `above=3mm`.  Are the axes drawn with a width of `0.8pt`?

Comment: @Adelyn Check out [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192060/title-distance-to-axis-labels) answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Based on the post that you suggested and a comment from Zarko, I guess that `title style={align=center, font=\bfseries,above=3mm}` or `title style={align=center, font=\bfseries, yshift=3mm}`  is what I need.  Is the anchor for the title node at the south by default?  I added `anchor=north, inner sep=0pt` to the `title style=` and got the same display.

Comment: Yes, the anchor is south by default, but this is relative to the coordinate `(current axis.north)`. The anchor is not relative to the entire axis, so setting `anchor = north` probably resulted in the title just looking like it was pushed lower. Check out page 342 of the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf). In your `title style`, add `at = (current axis.south)` to place the title below the axis, and then you will want to change the anchor to `anchor = north`, and fine tune with a `yshift`. I'll update my answer above with this change.

Comment: Thanks for giving the code for the display below the `y`-axis.  You said that the anchor is south relative to `(current axis.north)` but not "relative to the entire axis."  Please explain this.

Comment: @Adelyn What I meant is that the anchor location is at the top of the y-axis, so that if you only specified `anchor = north`, this will place the title text directly below the top of the y-axis, not below the entire axis. This is why we needed to use `at = (current axis.south)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36891/discussion-between-anthony-mottaz-and-adelyn).

Comment: I understand that the default positioning for the title is centered horizontally above the `axis` environment.  (I could have `at=(current axis.north)` as a value in the `title style`, but that would be redundant.)  Since I have `anchor=south west` as a value for `ylabel style`, I guess that `yshift=3mm` in the `title style` will raise the title `3mm` above the `y` designating the `y`-axis.  Is that correct?

Comment: I think that I prefer the positioning of the title using the values `at=(current axis.south)`, `anchor=north`, and `yshift=-3mm` in the `title style`.

Answer (score 0):

1. For bigger distance between graph just ad some space between the,
   for example `\qquad` or as it is in code below `\hspace{4em}` (or
   other distance according to your wish). Note: your graphs are not
   centered in text width (if this matter).
2. For title above graphs you need only to add to axis option `title
       style={align=center, font=\bfseries}` and `title={... \\ ....}`
3. Third wish is already achieved with measure in second item :-)

All this gives:

[image]

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image, clip=false,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,ymax=4,
    restrict y to domain=-4:4,
    %enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
    title style={align=center, font=\bfseries},
    title={The graph of an \\ increasing function}
]

\addplot [domain=-3:-2] {-3};
\addplot [domain=-2:-1] {-2};
\addplot [domain=-1:0] {-1};
\addplot [line width=1.2pt, domain=0:1] {0};
\addplot [domain=1:2] {1};
\addplot [domain=2:3] {2} node [pos=1, anchor=south west, font=\footnotesize] {$y=f(x)$};

\draw[fill] (-3,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (-2,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (-1,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (1,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (2,2) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\draw [fill=white] (-2,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (-1,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (0,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (2,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (3,2) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hspace{4em}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in, clip=false,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-8:8,
   % enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
    title style={align=center, font=\bfseries},
    title={The graph of a strictly \\ increasing function}
]
\addplot [domain=-2:2] {x^3} node [pos=1, anchor=west, font=\footnotesize] {$y=g(x)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

About line widths: this depend on personal test. Different people, different taste ... If you liked more "bold" just increase their thickness. As I change position of axis labels according to my taste :-)

*Edit:* Little **of topic**: the first graph, as it is, can be drawn much simpler:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    L/.style = {% as Line
                {Circle[width=1mm,length=1mm]}-%
                {Circle[width=1mm,length=1mm,open,line width=0.4pt]},
                shorten >=-0.6mm, shorten <=-0.6mm,
               }    ]
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image, clip=false,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,ymax=4,
    restrict y to domain=-4:4,
    %enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
    title style={draw,align=center, font=\bfseries},
    title={The graph of an \\ increasing function}
]

\draw[red,L] (-3,-3) edge (-2,-3)
             (-2,-2) edge (-1,-2)
             (-1,-1) edge (0,-1)
             (0,0) edge[thick] (1,0)
             (1,1) edge (2,1)
             (2,2)  --  (3,2) node[anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize] {$y=f(x)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, omitted as all `\addplot ...` and separated draw of circles are replaced with lines with filled and open circles on the ends.

And **on-topic**: On positioning of nodes you have more possibilities:

- define anchor of node and say for example `\node[anchor=south] at (<coordinate>) ...` and node's anchor `south` will lie on `<coordinate>`
- use option `above`, for example `\node[above] at (<coordinate>) ...` and node will lie on the same place as before
- define anchor of node and after that use option `above`, for example `\node[anchor=north,above] at (<coordinate>) ...` and node will lie as before regardless that regarding to anchor one expect different (in this case `above` override `anchor`)
- define anchor of node after use of option `above`, for example: `\node[above,anchor=north] at (<coordinate>) ...`. Now the node position will differ from before cases. On `<coordinate>` will lie node's anchor `north`

With drawing nodes border (as shown on figure) can help to see, where is text baseline. Its position in node is depend on text depth, if it is not extra defined. For details is very recommencement to read TikZ manual "17.4.4 Text Parameters: Height and Depth of Text" on page 226. and than "17.5 Positioning Nodes" on page 227.

Comment: I copied your `axis` options for `title style` and `title` but I got the title typeset much closer to the `y` designating the `y`axis.  Did you get the display you posted just from your code?

Comment: I got a display that is much closer to what you have when I added `anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, above=3mm` as options to `title style=`, and I got the same display when I replaced `anchor=north` with `anchor=south`.  Why is the `anchor` value ignored?

Comment: of course the image is generated by posted code. I tested with v. 1.11 as well with v 1.13. In both cases I got the same result. In graph I used default position for titles. If you like to change distance to graph, than the simple way is use `\yshift= ...`. With `above=...` you always override `anchors=...`. In testing of different position try to ad option `draw` to tile options. With this you will better see, where the title is.