# ylabel and title overlapped

Tags: pgfplots

I copied the code in the accepted answer in [How can I adjust the position of xlabel and ylabel with pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122747/126386), and I added a `title={title with very long lines}`.  Is there a way to move the `title` above the `ylabel`?  I wish to keep the position of the axis labels.  I tried searching "pgfplots title position", but I got info for axis titles instead of the title for the whole graph.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{
pgfplots,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2,
minor tick num=2,
axis y line=middle,
axis x line=middle,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=west,
},
every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=south,
},
title={title with very long lines}
]
\addplot[blue,mark=none]
plot[domain=-5:5,samples=40]
(\x,{sin(\x r)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ylabel and title overlapped]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192062/ I suppose?

Comment: thanks for info.  i marked as dupe.